# How do I create a pure data-only code object in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, constants

We have a complex multi-core system with multiple elf files that are built using GCC tools.  We want to move the const configuration data out to it's own elf file to be able to load it separately from the other elements into its own area of memory that various code elements access.  This configuration data depends on various #include files and needs to be compiled to create the proper data structure.

I have this working now but with one caveat. The linked config includes a tiny bit of code in .init and .fini sections and I cannot figure out how to build without ANY code.  I just want the const data structures. It seems there should be a way to specify that we don't want this code at all.

Comment: Although I saw such a things being done, I would recommend against it, because `gcc` goal is to compile executable code, and it wants to optimize away stuff that it is not aware of being used. So better create a python or other script that will read some textual config files and generate raw binary files that you can load into the memory.

Comment: Well, _what_ is the `.init/.fini` code exactly (e.g. disassemble it)? Is it just (e.g.) `void init(void) { return; }`? Or, does it it do some real init, such as calling [c++] constructors for global objects? Can you edit your question and post the [representative] code for the const data?

Comment: With GNU ld, you can use `-b binary <NameOfFile>` to specify the input file is a raw binary data file. E.g., `ld -r -b binary foo.bin -o object.o` will read `foo.bin` and create an object file containing its data named `object.o`.

Comment: "This configuration data depends on various #include files and needs to be compiled to create the proper data structure." This is why I cannot just have some tool build a binary image. It is built by compiling values found in various #include files. It is also an over-simplification to state that gcc only builds "executable" code. It builds "code" and these config structures are code. They just need to be independent because the system is delivered with prebuilt and tested binary executables and the config is supplied separately to customize how it works.

Comment: @RDFlorida: Compile the configuration data. Write it to a binary file. Use `ld -r -b binary …` to make it into an object file.

Comment: @RDFlorida: [A simple test](https://godbolt.org/z/hj4YvjMEG) does not show GCC building any code into a module that contains only object definitions. Edit the question to provide a [mre].